# what is the weight loss calculator Formula?

Tags: calculation

which must contain  weight,height,age,gender,level of activity and amount to loss weight. The weight and height in both cm and inches.

Comment: I find this question not very constructive, what do you expect the answer to be and what are you going to do with that knowledge? If you want to know how much you need to exercise to lose weight, ask that.

Comment: I think you're talking about BMI (Body Mass Index)?

Comment: Are you asking for the mathematical formula or an implementation of one? The National Institute of Diabetes and Digestive and Kidney Diseases has a nice little [body weight *simulator*](http://bwsimulator.niddk.nih.gov/) (for weight gain and loss). There are [links](http://www2.niddk.nih.gov/NIDDKLabs/LBM/) there related to the publications about the modeling of it.

Comment: Matt, that is really cool. I am going to write a similar one in Silverlight. I have already written a small Silverlight control to calculate your AMR at http://kaucher.blogspot.com/2011/03/calculate-you-basal-and-actual.html You've inspired me to do some work!

Answer (score 1):

Likely what you are asking for is the formula to calculate your Basal Metabolic Rate. Here is the Harris-Benedict equation for BMR:

> Women: BMR = 655 + ( 9.6 x weight in kilos ) + ( 1.8 x height in cm )
>   - ( 4.7 x age in years )
>
> Men: BMR = 66 + ( 13.7 x weight in kilos ) + ( 5 x height in cm ) - ( 6.8 x age in years )

Your actual caloric needs are fairly subjective. A good way to get an estimate is via the activity level score. Your activity level score is based on how you work (sit in a chair all day? Sedentarty, walking around a warehouse? Light activity. Lifting and moving things around a warehouse? Moderate activity. Two serious workouts a day? High physical activity.)

- Sedentary Physical Activity Level = 1.1
- Light Physical Activity Level
  = 1.2
- Moderate Physical Activity Level = 1.3
- High Physical Activity Level = 1.4

Once you have your BMR multiply it by your activity level score and this will give you your AMR (Active Metabolic Rate or some say Actual Metabolic Rate). Use that as a starting point. Track your calories and weight for a few weeks and see if they stay level. If so start by cutting around 500 to 700 calories from your daily intake. 500 calories per day is theoretically going to lead to weight loss of one pound in a week. You may be different so this might take some experimentation. You will eventually hit a plateau and you can then cut another 500 to 700 calories (or more if required).